# golang outlook smtp send mail

Tags: go, outlook, smtp

I have following code and it throws ""5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [ZR0P278CA0110.CHEP278.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]" error.

the code:

```
func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "****")
    m.SetHeader("To", "***")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Title")
    m.SetBody("text/html", "Message")
    d := gomail.NewDialer("smtp.office365.com", 587, "****", "****")
    d.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf(err.Error())
        //return err
    }
}
```

Comment: It means what it says; you failed to authenticate, or perhaps you are not authorized to use that SMTP server.

Comment: I enabled smtp server on outlook admin config, also username and password are correct.

Comment: I would trust the error message more. Perhaps you can tweak up the logging and see what exactly you are sending to the server and what exactly it responds.

Comment: This is most likely due to an issue with your account setup; Microsoft have some [troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-lob-applications-that-send-email-using-off#error-authentication-unsuccessful) but you may also want to consider trying an [app password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/account-billing/manage-app-passwords-for-two-step-verification-d6dc8c6d-4bf7-4851-ad95-6d07799387e9).

Comment: See [535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/512954/535-57139-authentication-unsuccessful.html)